# can`t encode or decode to see "ç" on my string

Tags: python, html, unicode, utf-8, encode

I'm taking a body from an email and trying to make some comparisons and print.

I'm not getting it because my string has special characters, python is returning me = E7 instead of ç. There are some strange codes too, I believe it's from html:

```
'\r\n________________________________\r\nDe: Transfer=EAncia de Cliente\r\nEnviado'

'BATIST=\r\nA'

'solicita=E7=E3o'
```

I've tried everything, the last thing I used was:

```
bytes.fromhex("E7").decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

which returns "ç" correctly but when trying to use the other string it gives me an error:

```
a = '\r\n________________________________\r\nDe: Transfer=EAncia de Cliente\r\nEnviado: segunda-feira'

bytes.fromhex(a).decode("ISO-8859-1")

ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 2
```

can you help me?
my language is: pt br

Answer (score 0):

The reason your second `fromhex` is failing is because you didn't give it hex data.  Hex data can only contain the characters A-F and 0-9 and there must be an even number of them.  See how you correctly used `fromhex` the first time with "E7".

I think your data is in "quoted-printable" format and you should try https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/quopri.html

To install it, use `python -m pip install quopri`